# retrive hidden input value in jsp scriptlet variable without submit page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have set hidden value in html as below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="testUsr"/>
```

I want this value in jsp scriptlet variable just like below:

```
<% user %> = docuemnt.getElementById("userId").value;
```

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. What you need to do is send the value to the `servlet` either

1. By passing it in the url
2. Or sending it as a parameter in the request using the `request` object in the `jsp`
3. Or by placing the hidden field in a `<form>` and calling a `servlet` on click of `submit`
   like so:

   `<form method='get' action='myservlet'>`

   `<!--Your other fields-->`

   `<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="testUsr"/>`

   `<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>`

   `</form>`

Comment: It's very late for the comment, I just want to know how to execute the 2nd method, **Sending as parameter in request object** ??

Answer (score 0):

After the form is submitted, the JSP that the form was submitted to can retrieve the value by

```
request.getParameter("userId")
```

Be aware also that "hidden" doesn't mean anything in this context but that the input is not a visible input box. The user can still see this value if they view source in the browser.